# Return a list of string letters grouped by two

Tags: python

I have a string made of letters and numbers and i want a list of these grouped by two, ie I have :

```
shv = "abcdef"
```

And i want:

```
('ab'; 'cd', 'ef')
```

I can do :

```
thv  = (shv[0:2], shv[2:4], shv[4:6])
```

But somehow this seems a little bit ungeneric  : is there a better way, ie for a string with any side and with another grouping value (by groups of n letters for example)

Comment: In your example, you show a tuple (ignoring the typo where you want a comma instead of a semi-colon).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a list comprehension and utilize the `step` argument of [`range`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#range):

```
[shv[i:i+2] for i in range(0, len(shv)-1, 2)]
```

For arbitrary `n`:

```
def my_awesome_grouping_function(shv, n):
    return [shv[i:i+n] for i in range(0, len(shv)-(n-1), n)]
```

Demo:

```
>>> shv="abcdef"
>>> [shv[i:i+2] for i in range(0, len(shv)-1, 2)]
['ab', 'cd', 'ef']
>>> [shv[i:i+3] for i in range(0, len(shv)-2, 3)]
['abc', 'def']
```

I trimmed the upper bound because I figured you wouldn't want any trailing incomplete pairs. Do you? If you just go to `len(shv)` I believe you will get the remaining `len(shv) % n` letters in the last element.

```
>>> shv="abcdefgh"
>>> [shv[i:i+3] for i in range(0, len(shv), 3)]
['abc', 'def', 'gh']
>>> [shv[i:i+3] for i in range(0, len(shv)-1, 3)]
['abc', 'def', 'gh']
>>> [shv[i:i+3] for i in range(0, len(shv)-2, 3)]
['abc', 'def']
```

(As you see above it has to be `len(shv)-(n-1)` for the trimming to work.)

Comment: @DSM I think it technically works for even length strings, but you're absolutely right :P. If 2rs2ts fixes it though, I'll grant it my upvote, as it is the clearest method of doing what the OP wants.

Comment: @DSM I posted this without testing hoping I hadn't made a mistake. let me test and correct

Comment: @2rs2ts: Hint: it's the `len(shv)-1` part.

Comment: Haha woops exclusive bounds!

Comment: @JoelCornett: something even more fundamental than that, actually. :^)

Comment: @DSM Might help if `my_awesome_grouping_function` actually took `shv` as an argument, you mean?  ;)

Comment: @SilasRay: when I first commented there was no `my_awesome_grouping_function`-- I was getting at the exclusive bound issue, so that all the pieces were 1 character long..

Comment: About the `len(shv)-1` part, what do you guys think? Does OP want the trailing odd letter?

Comment: that's exactly what i was looking for ! thanks a whole bunch !

Answer (score 4):

I'd go with `textwrap` for this, gives an elegant solution:

```
>>> import textwrap
>>>
>>> shv = "abcdef"
>>> thv = textwrap.wrap(shv, 2)
>>> thv
['ab', 'cd', 'ef']
```

If you have a mismatched size this is what you get:

```
>>> thv = textwrap.wrap(shv, 4)
>>> thb
['abcd', 'ef']
```

Should you only want to include "complete" substrings, you can use the following comprehension:

```
>>> thv = [substr for substr in textwrap.wrap(shv, 4) if len(substr) == 4]
>>> thv
['abcd']
```

Comment: Maybe that last comprehension could better expressed as `thv = textwrap.wrap(shv, 4)` and then `thv = thv if len(thv[-1]) == 4 else thv[:len(thv)-1]`?

Comment: @2rs2ts yeah, I suppose the short entry will always be the last one

Comment: `textwrap.wrap('as dfgh', 2) == ['as', 'df', 'gh']`

Comment: @user2357112 Yep, but OP didn't seem very concerned about multiple words, so I wasn't either

Answer (score 2):

How about

```
>>> import re
>>> re.findall("..", shv)
['ab', 'cd', 'ef']
```

For arbitrary lengths (for example `3`), use the `{n}` quantifier:

```
>>> shv = "abcdefghi"
>>> re.findall(".{3}", shv)
['abc', 'def', 'ghi']
```

If you want to use up remaining letters that don't match entirely, use `{1,n}`:

```
>>> shv = "abcdefghijk"
>>> re.findall(".{1,3}", shv)
['abc', 'def', 'ghi', 'jk']
```

Comment: Should probably add `"." * n` for arbitrary groupoing.

Comment: I... huh. It's short, neater than the ranges and slices, and avoids having to think about boundary values and off-by-one errors, but I feel conflicted about the regex use nonetheless. Not sure why. Upvoted, though.

Comment: Don't you need the `DOTALL` flag, though?

Answer (score 2):

nice little trick with copied iterators.

```
tuple(''.join(i) for i in zip(*[iter(shv)]*2))
```

alternate version if you feel sentimental for the sad lonely character, being left out at the end of an odd length string.

```
from itertools import izip_longest
tuple(''.join(i) for i in izip_longest(*[iter(shv)]*2, fillvalue=''))
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a way with regular expressions.

```
import re

shv = "abcdef"
print re.findall('..',shv)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
shv = "abcdef"
[''.join(item) for item in zip(shv[0::2],shv[1::2])]
```

Comment: `shv[0::2],shv[1::2]` somehow seems less nice than `*[iter(shv)]*2`

Comment: @njzk2 I disagree but only through ignorance. I don't know how `*[iter(shv)]*2` works, while using string slicing is abundantly clear to me. Aren't strings already iterables? Why are we calling `iter` on it? I realize it doesn't work if we don't, but the fact that I don't know WHY means it's hard for me to use that method :)

Comment: @adsmith `iter` creates an `iterator` object. I think what we're getting with `*[iter(shv)]*2` is a list containing the same `iterator` twice, and we're unpacking it for the arguments to `zip`.

Comment: @2rs2ts I guess I understand, since using `*[shv]*2` unpacks two string literals, we end up zipping to `('a','a'),('b','b'),('c','c')` while referencing the SAME iterator makes sure that every zip call advances it using `.__next__`. It's just...arcane.

Comment: @adsmith I think it's brilliant really :)

Comment: @adsmith : it has the advantage that just changing the `2` into any parameter is sufficient, while the slice method does not allow that, as you need to declare `n` slices.